# How to upload rss file and update it when need in azure

Tags: azure, rss

I want to use logic app with my rss connections. 
I created rss by [this](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/RSSFeed/article.html#read) tutorial. 
I am searching about suitable azure service how to upload it and set rss url in logic app according to this.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should know, the logic app rss connector could not update, check the [connector reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/rss/), it only have a List all RSS feed items action except the trigger.

If you still want to use logic app to do this thing with azure service, you could use azure function to implement it, and if you want to upload the file you could use azure storage blob. And the function type you could use HTTP trigger function , also azure function support java, more details you could refer to this tutorial:[Azure Functions Java developer guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-java).

Comment: thanks. actually curentlly I used logic app with this ss file: http://www.ynet.co.il/Integration/StoryRss1854.xml. when have new item it send me in email. it is work perfect. I want that I create rss file and put the rss url suite. currently I also use azure functions for to send client notifications when have new item. it is done via HTTP trigger. I just need to know how to create rss and save it with domain for put this url instead of what have now.

Comment: If that, you could use logic app and function to do it.

Comment: how? how I can produce url for logic app?

Comment: I want create and put my url of rss file instead that:  ynet.co.il/Integration/StoryRss1854.xml.

Comment: You could use azure function to create the file and save it to azure storage.